# WCF & Azure: Make a worker role wait till it receives data from another worker role

Tags: wcf, azure

I am quite new to WCF. I followed a tutorial on how to use Internal Endpoints (WCF) to make a Role to Role communication. [Link for the tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iwOOxQc8Rs0)

They actually create multiple instance of a worker role and poke each other.

The code is

```
            foreach (var ep in endPoints)
        {
            IService1 worker = WorkerRole.factory.CreateChannel(new EndpointAddress(string.Format("net.tcp://{0}/Service1", ep.IPEndpoint)));

            try
            {
                Trace.WriteLine(worker.SayHello(currentInstance.Id.ToString()), "Information");
                ((ICommunicationObject)worker).Close();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Trace.TraceError("unable to poke worker role instance '{0}'. {1}", ep.RoleInstance.Id, e.Message);
                ((ICommunicationObject)worker).Abort();
            }
        }
```

But I want to make a worker role wait till it is being poked by other worker role. Say for example, there are 3 worker roles. The worker role 2 and worker role 3 should wait till it is being poked by worker role 1.

Can anyone tell me how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To do this diectly see http://blog.structuretoobig.com/post/2010/02/03/Windows-Azure-Role-Communication.aspx, using the Azure Service Bus see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/09/30/implementing-reliable-inter-role-communication-using-windows-azure-appfabric-service-bus-observer-pattern-amp-parallel-linq.aspx , or you can use the Azure Queue to communicate between roles, or you could use the Azure Caching Service ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278356.aspx )

Answer (score 0):

I think I would architect this slightly differently.

Instead of having worker roles exposing WCF Endpoints and sending messages between them it may be neater to use queues.

Messages can be posted to queues and picked up and processed by other worker roles.  This introduces a certain amount of durability in that if a worker role that is supposed to receive a message is down for any reason it can carry on processing those messages on its queue when it comes back up.  Also any unhandled exceptions that happen whilst processing a message will mean that the message reappears on the queue after a certain timeout period.  If your app/site really takes off you can add additional instances of those worker roles to process the messages on the queues more quickly.

Therefore by using queues you have a certain amount of additional durability and its easier to scale up later.

There is a good intro to using queues [on the developer fusion website](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/120197/using-the-queuing-service-in-windows-azure/)